# How can I test whether a string ends with a particular substring in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to find out whether a string ends with a particular substring or not.

Some things I considered, and tried:

#### A builtin

There doesn't appear to be an `ends_with` string filter in Shopify Liquid.

#### A regex

There's also no regex matching functionality.

#### Strip from the end, then compare

In some languages, the string to strip from the end of a string can be overridden. Not so in Shopify Liquid; it'll only strip space.

#### Split on the substring, then inspect the results

I tried `assign tmp = str | split: substr` and then inspecting the results, thinking there might be something I can do with that. For example, I thought maybe if the last entry was an empty string, I might be able to figure it out from there. But by way of example, splitting on `X`, `..X..` and `..X..X` give the same output of `["..", ".."]`, so we won't get anywhere here.

#### Remove the last matching substring, append the substring, then compare

This actually works, but it's pretty horrible.

```
{% liquid
  assign tmp = str | remove_last: substr | append: substr
  if tmp == str
    assign output = true
  else
    assign output = false
  endif
%}
```

#### Slice the end of the string, and compare to the substring

This works too, and you'd think it'd be shorter code, but thanks to Liquid not supporting parens (as far as I can tell), it actually ends up longer:

```
{% liquid
  assign tmp_neg_substr_size = 0 | minus: substr.size
  assign tmp_ending = str | slice: tmp_neg_substr_size, substr.size
  if tmp_ending == substr
    assign output = true
  else
    assign output = false
  endif
%}
```

---

Are there any better solutions? Or is there a way to turn my solution into a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would have done it:

1. Split the text word by word: `assign worlds = text_to_search | split: ' '`
2. Get the last word: `assign last_word = worlds | last`
3. Check if the last word matches the word you are looking for:

```
if last_word == text_to_find
  assign last_word_match = true
endif
```

Here is the final code:

```
{%- liquid
  assign last_word_match = false
  assign text_to_search = 'Hello world'
  assign text_to_find = 'world'
  assign worlds = text_to_search | split: ' '
  assign last_word = worlds | last
  if last_word == text_to_find
    assign last_word_match = true
  endif
-%}
```

Comment: This won't work for me because I can't be sure the substring is a word. It might be multiple words, or something like `_blue`. I'm looking for a general solution.